# how can I implement a program to interact with me using python?

Tags: python, shell

I want write a very simple program with python:

```
while True:
    # 1. input = get sys.std

    if input == 'y':
        print "yes"
    elif input == 'n':
        print "no"
    else input == 'q':
        # 2. quit
```

how can I implement `step 1` and `step 2`?

Comment: Are you asking about `input` (`raw_input` in Python 2)?

Comment: Use `if elif else ` to check multiple conditions. check following answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need user input you have two ways to do it:

```
# Get shell command line arguments
import sys
print( sys.argv )

# If you want user input
user_input = raw_input('Please enter your value: ')
```

If you want to exit currently executing script you can use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit). Make sure you call the exit from the main script, unintercepted by any `try... except`.

I highly recommend you read [Python tutorials](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/stdlib.html#brief-tour-of-the-standard-library)

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `raw_input()` to get value from user.
2. **Do not use variable name which Python already define** e.g. `input`
3. **Use `if elif else` loop to check condition**.
4. Use `break` keyword to exit from the while loop.

**Demo**:

```
while True:
    # 1. input = get sys.std
    user_input = raw_input("Enter 'y' to print yes, 'n' to print 'no', " 
                           "and 'q' to quit: ")
    if user_input == 'y':
        print "yes"
    elif user_input == 'n':
        print "no"
    elif user_input == 'q':
        # 2. quit
        break
    else:
        print "Wrong input try again."
```

**Output**:

```
Enter 'y' to print yes, 'n' to print 'no' and 'q' break code: y
yes
Enter 'y' to print yes, 'n' to print 'no' and 'q' break code: n
no
Enter 'y' to print yes, 'n' to print 'no' and 'q' break code: y
yes
Enter 'y' to print yes, 'n' to print 'no' and 'q' break code: df
Wrong input try again.
Enter 'y' to print yes, 'n' to print 'no' and 'q' break code: q
```

---

**By Command Line**

Use `sys.argv` to get argument list, first element is py file name

**Demo**:

```
import sys
arguments = sys.argv
print "Arguments:", sys.argv
print "Type Arguments:", type(arguments)
```

**Output**:

```
Arguments: ['polydict.py', 'argument1', 'argument2']
Type Arguments: <type 'list'>
```

---

**Note**:

Use `input()` for Python 3.x

Use `raw_input()` for Python 2.x

Comment: @martineau: Yes, Updated now. Plz review again and if any more issue then tell me. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case it is python 2.x you are talking about you can use [`raw_input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) method :

```
name = raw_input("What's your name? ")
```

While in python 3.x you should use [`input`](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/python/hands-on/3.1/handsonHtml/io.html) method :

```
name = input("What's your name? ")
```

To terminate your program you can use [`sys.exit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit) :

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python3 you've an builtin called input

```
def Entersomething():
    myinp = input("Enter your options:")
    if myinp == 'y':
        print("yes")
    elif myinp =='n':
        print("no")
    elif myinp =='e':
        print("exit")

Entersomething()
```